# Changing the activity theme from within the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, themes, android-databinding

I will introduce my code first. Have a look at themes:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**AppTheme.Launcher** is used so that the user gets greeted with "splash screen". In `MainActivity` `onCreate` function I change the theme using `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)` and I also hide the action bar using `supportActionBar?.hide()`. My application is fragment-orientated. I have only one Activity that hosts navigation scheme which has several fragments. The problem is in this:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

In one of my fragments I want to show action bar again and I don't want my status bar to be translucent anymore, or in other words, I want it to be seen and for it to have a color `PrimaryDark`. To do this, I have written a function inside the **MainActivity**.

```
    fun clearTranslucent() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val w: Window = window
            w.clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
            )
            w.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        }
    }
```

[image: Weird status bar behavior]

This is where the fun begins. For some reason this white space gets added in between. If I decide to comment out this line `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` the results is even more weird. Status bar becomes **grayed** and my `ScrollView` stops working. This same error follows me in several fragments when I want to change the original Theme of the Activity. I've tried changing the theme from within the fragment but it doesn't work. Read somewhere that you can change Activity theme only from within the `onCreate` function. Why my layout misbehaves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you are describing are known bugs.

You can only set the theme of the activity before the onCreate for this activity happens

So you have two options :

1. open a new activity with said fragment, and set its theme in the
   android manifest.
2. set the theme of the activity inside your fragment, and write logic in oncreate to display your fragment, after you change the
   theme, call activity.recreate() which will make the activity
   relaunch itself and thus applying your theme.

Comment: So there is no other more neat way to do this? This would mean that I would call .recreate() every time I want to hide or show status bar from my fragments?

Comment: unfortunately yes